# Hydration completed but contains mismatches - Ascii art in a vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pre, hydration

I have an ascii art that is displayed in the `{{ name }}` of the component. During development, I got a vue warn:

`Hydration text content mismatch in <pre>`

And an error:

`Hydration completed but contains mismatches.` in `runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4525:14`

During build, I get this error:

`Hydration completed but contains mismatches.`

The error is found in `dist/assets/index.js`

```
<template>
            <div class="ascii">
                <pre id="ascii-art">{{ name }}</pre>
            </div>
    </template>
        
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "Header",
        components: {
            Prompt
        },
    
    data() {
                try {
                    return {
                        name: // ascii art
                    };
                } catch (error) {
                    // Handle the error
                    console.error("Error occurred while initializing 'name':", error);
                    return {
                        name: 'Error occurred while initializing name property',
                    };
                }
            }
    }
    </script>
```

I have tried putting it in a try catch block and console.log the error but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

hydration needs no difference between result HTML that client rendered and result HTML that server rendered. So you needed to render DOM(ascii art string) at mounted cycle not created cycle like below.

```js
<template>
            <div class="ascii">
                <pre id="ascii-art">{{ name }}</pre>
            </div>
    </template>
        
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "Header",
        components: {
            Prompt
        },
    
    data() {
                return {
                        name: 'Error occurred while initializing name property',
                    };
            },
    mounted() {
        try {
            this.name = 'ascii art';
        }
    },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: try {} alone is syntax error and it doesn't serve a purpose. The OP states that the error occurs at build time. How can this change prevent it?

Comment: Add catch syntax even if there is no syntax inside the curly braces.

Comment: I tried your method. It worked in development but not during actual build time. I am still getting the errors